# Временное закрытие сетевого доступа к папке

Tags: 1с, share, windows-server

Добрый день.

Есть сервер 1С на Windows Server 2008R2, на время обновления базы необходимо закрывать сетевой доступ к этой папке, чтобы никто не смог зайти и сделать изменения. После же обновления необходимо восстанавливать сетевой доступ к папке. Самое главное, чтобы права на папку не слетали.

Помогите, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удаление общей папки:

```
net share /delete shara_1c
```

Создание общей папки:

```
net share share_1c=c:\1cBuhgalteriya /grant:user1,full /grant:Администраторы,full /grant:buhgalter1,full
```

`user1`, `Администраторы` и `buhgalter1` - пользователи, которым даете права на доступ к папке.

Подробнее можно почитать, выполнив команду `net share /?`.

Answer (score 1):

А типовой функционал не подходит?

1. Создать файл `1Cv8.cdn` в папке с информационной базой содержащий строку:

   ```
   {1,19800101000000,20791231235959,"","123",""}
   ```

   Все кто был через пару минут отвалятся, а новый никто не зайдет.
2. Открыть конфигуратор с параметром `/UC123` и спокойно обновлять.
3. Удалить файл.